# Purchase Timer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm looking to create one of those purchase timers sort of like what they've got on Ticketmaster, where you have x minutes to pay for your order before it is rolled back.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, though. Looked at the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem and the railscast about it after somebody suggested those, and it seemed like the functionality is different -- delayed job allows you to delay an action, but doesn't make that delay conditional on anything else's happening, and I can't figure out how to do so.

I'm basically looking for something that allows me to

a) have (pseudo)code sort of like this

```
if job_timer == 0
   @order.destroy
   #Some redirect/flash stuff
end
```

b) display that timer on the page (ie, "You have 3 min, 25 seconds left to pay before your order is reversed.")

Any ideas what to do/where to look?

Thanks,

Sasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delayed_job is what you are looking for.

For example, you can have a function that goes through all the order objects.

```rb
def purge_orders
  # purge_at is an attribute of order that contains 
  # the datetime when the order should be deleted.
  Order.where("purge_at >= #{DateTime.current}").each {|order| order.destroy }
end
```

The second question is more of a javascript question. The idea is, Rails pass the remaining time to the client, and javascript creates a timer out of the remaining time given from Rails side. Put the javascript in your view file. Ideally you should isolate javascript in your assets folder, but I am not going to do that for you here.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = <%= @order.purge_at - DateTime.current %>;
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

[Source for the original javascript code](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. So, I should probably create a function that simultaneously starts a delay_job on the relevant order instance when it is first created and assigns purge_at's value. So in the model in a after_create call or something. Then just throw that purge_order method into my order model as well? And call it on the page with the timer?

Comment: When user submits an order, you can make `purge_at = created_at + 3.days` so that the order gets destroyed 3 days later. Set delayed job to run every 5 minutes or something and it'll go through Order and delete all the order that's passed the purge_at time.

Comment: That works reasonably well if the time the user has to pay in is measured in days. If it's more like a few minutes, getting accurate results requires running a job every few seconds. That feels pretty inefficient (hence my suggestion of one scheduled job per order), although it might be equivalent (or even superior) for a sufficiently large volume of orders.

Comment: It depends how many orders this application gets per day. In my scenario, I make 288 queries/day. So if he gets more or less around the same orders, it makes sense to go with your way. However, if you get thousands of orders per day, making thousands of database query is really costly.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't believe delayed_job handles recurring, scheduled jobs like this out of the box. There's a couple of forks that add it, or you can handle it yourself with something like Whenever (http://github.com/javan/whenever).

Answer (score 1):

While delayed_job probably can handle this, it's not quite as simple as the previous answer suggests.

I think it will look something like this:

order.rb:

```
after_create :schedule_check_payment

def schedule_check_payment
  self.delay(:run_at => 5.minutes.from_now, :queue => :payment_checks).check_payment
end

def check_payment
  self.reload
  unless payment_exists #check if the user has paid
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

I can think of a couple of caveats to this technique as well:

1. The check will run as soon as a delayed job worker is free after the 5 minutes, but if the queue gets backed up, it could potentially take longer. This is why I specify a queue for the delayed processing. I believe you can set up delayed_job so that one (or more) of it's workers will only process jobs from that queue. That way, if you start using delayed_job for other, slower tasks in the future (and you may well, it's an incredibly handy gem), they aren't as likely to bog down your payment checks by consuming all the delayed processing resources.
2. Delayed job serializes objects that delayed methods are called on. If something about the Order itself determines wether or not it's been paid, make sure to reload it in the check_payment method (that's why that's there), because the object may not otherwise realize that that attribute has been changed in the 5 minutes since the job was scheduled. That's why I call `self.reload` in the check_payment method.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! So what is :payment_checks here? (In the first method). And how do you reload the order object? Just by calling it in a different method as you do above?

Comment: @Sasha `:payment_checks` is the name of a queue - it's mostly an organizational technique, but you can set up delayed_job so that one of it's workers only handles jobs from that queue. That makes it less likely that the problem in 1. occurs, because a slow, long running job is less likely to prevent check_payment from running when it should.

Comment: @Sasha And you can reload the object by calling `self.reload` on it, as I do in the example. Sorry about the double post.

Comment: `:run_at => 5.minutes.from_now` . This might be okay if you have a dozen orders / day or something. But if you have anything more than several hundreds of orders, it's going to become problematic. If you have thousands of order/day, well get ready to pay hefty amount of money for Amazon instances. Imagine if you had to query database for every single order you make. It's unrealistic.

Comment: @garbagecollection It's a fair point - for whatever your acceptable margin of error on order deletion is, once you have more than one order on average per that time period, it will be more efficient to delete them in batches. Until then, it will be better to have one job per order.

Comment: @garbagecollection/MrTheWalrus. Thanks! I think I'll start small for now, cause it looks easier and I don't expect too much traffic at the moment. As the site (hopefully) expands its base and I become better at Rails, I'll give it a second look with an eye towards efficiency/cost. Thanks so much, both of you, for the help.